# instagram bot using instabot in python

Tags: python

Hi guys I did this Instagram bot by seeing it on the internet.In this i used 'like, follow, and comment on post' methods but I am not comfortable with this and to run the whole program it took around 20-25 min, can anyone tell me how to modify this so it becomes more efficient and any other methods to use and fast it up a little bit

```
import os
import glob
cookie_del=glob.glob('config/*cookie.json')
os.remove(cookie_del[0])
from instabot import Bot
from time import sleep
insta_bot=Bot()

try:
    insta_bot.login(username='user',password='pass')
except:
    print(Exception)
sleep(10)

try:
    insta_bot.follow_users(['user','user'])
except:
    print(Exception)


sleep(10)

try:
    insta_bot.send_message('hi','user name')
except:
    print(Exception)

sleep(30)
try:
    insta_bot.like_user('user name',amount=2,filtration=False)
except:
    print(Exception)
sleep(45)

try:
    take_id=insta_bot.get_user_id_from_username('username') 
    get_mediaID=insta_bot.get_last_user_medias(take_id,count=2)
    insta_bot.comment(get_mediaID[0],'hi')
except:
    print(Exception)
sleep(20)

followers=insta_bot.get_user_followers('username')
sleep(15)

following=insta_bot.get_user_following('username')
sleep(10)
for items in followers:
    print(insta_bot.get_username_from_user_id(items))
sleep(10)
for item in following:
    print(insta_bot.get_username_from_user_id(item))
insta_bot.logout()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! I removed all sleep functions from the code.

```
import os
import glob
from instabot import Bot

cookie_del = glob.glob('config/*cookie.json')
os.remove(cookie_del[0])
insta_bot = Bot()

try:
    insta_bot.login(username='user', password='pass')
except:
    print(Exception)

try:
    insta_bot.follow_users(['user', 'user'])
except:
    print(Exception)

try:
    insta_bot.send_message('hi', 'user name')
except:
    print(Exception)

try:
    insta_bot.like_user('user name', amount=2, filtration=False)
except:
    print(Exception)

try:
    take_id = insta_bot.get_user_id_from_username('username')
    get_mediaID = insta_bot.get_last_user_medias(take_id, count=2)
    insta_bot.comment(get_mediaID[0], 'hi')
except:
    print(Exception)

followers = insta_bot.get_user_followers('username')

following = insta_bot.get_user_following('username')
for items in followers:
    print(insta_bot.get_username_from_user_id(items))
for item in following:
    print(insta_bot.get_username_from_user_id(item))
insta_bot.logout()
```